# read all file names in a directory

Tags: java, file, io, path, nullpointerexception

I am trying to read all file names in a directory using java, i wrote the code and understand the process of writing it. However when I call String[] listOfFiles = folder.list(); it returns null (i get null pointer) I also tried listFiles() and have the same result. please tell me what am i doing wrong here is my directory [image]

```
private void getAllFileNames(){
    /*
        File file =new File(filePathAndName);
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println( "File: " + filePathAndName + "\n" + "AbsPath: " + path );*/

String filePathAndName = "resourses/amex";
    File folder = new File(filePathAndName);
    System.out.println (folder == null);
    String[] listOfFiles = folder.list();
    System.out.println (listOfFiles == null); //RETURNS TRUE
    System.out.println (listOfFiles.length);

        /*for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
        }*/


}
```

Comment: Typo: `resourses/amex` should be `resources/amex`

Comment: ok, i am officially going to sleep. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo.

```
String filePathAndName = "resourses/amex";
```

should be changed to:

```
String filePathAndName = "resources/amex";
```

Answer (score 1):

Atleast start with changing

```
String filePathAndName = "resourses/amex";
```

To

```
String filePathAndName = "resources/amex";
```

And see how it goes :)